# How to get prior notification that your home is under attack with enemies that attack your home in Hearthfire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I just started playing Hearthfire for the first time. I built a huge house with three wings. My problem is my steward Rayya, died easily to a bandit attack.

Now UESP did warn me about attacks from creatures, humans and dragons.

But what can I do to come on time to prevent my steward dying or if my children are under attack? I think if I was there I could have saved poor Rayya and my wife.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enemies won't attack your house unless you are in very close proximity. Avoid loitering around the immediate surroundings of your house, if you need to visit it - fast travel there directly, if you want to visit a nearby location, fast travel to the house and if the coast is clear walk to your destination. When you arrive at the house, use Detect life and Detect Death to identify hostiles and kill them as fast as you can.

Comment: Short of installing/creating a mod that disables that event, probably not.

Answer (score 2):

just equip your steward and wife with good armor and weapons and dont forget to give your children some daggers so they can help out since they are invincible in the game. (if you have the dawngaurd dlc than you can get a husky or a death hound to protect your house as a pet.

Answer (score 1):

Detect life/dead helps, keep strong pets and enchant the daggers you give to your children, as their attacks won't do much damage. If your animals are under attack from say giants the only thing you can really do if it's already attack it is attempt to distrace it, summon atronachs next to it or in the centre of the crowd of bandits. Try using spells like courage on your housecarl if they are under attack or support them with healing

Answer (score 1):

> Adopt a wardog
>
> Replace your housecarl's weapons and armor with improved sets.
>
> Pickpocket 100? Plant a strong dagger to your bard then Pickpocket the old one. He/she will equip the other one in her inventory.
>
> Give your children improved enchanted weapons.
>
> Pickpocket 100? Replace your carriage drivers weapon with an improved weapon the Pickpocket the old one.
>
> have a separate housecarl and steward.

(it doesn't take long to improve Pickpocket skill to 100) (replacing  items in an NPC's inventory must be done in the proper order. Plant the new weapon on their person > Then Pickpocket the old weapon.)

Comment: The problem with pickpocket isn't its difficulty, but the fact that you're now many levels higher than you need to be.  Ironically, in my later play-through, enemies are MUCH easier if I completely avoid pick-pocketing.